# Getting the Sum of Discounted Price

Tags: beginner, algorithm, c

Jojo is browsing the internet while suddenly he sees an ad about the new cafe. The promotion is if the price
of an item is N dollars, then you can buy the second item for half the price, the third item for a quarter of the
original price, and so on, but if it becomes less than M dollars, then you have to pay M dollars. He wonders
how much he has to pay if he buys K item.

---

Format Input

The first line will contain an integer `T`, the number of test cases.
Each test case will have 3 integers `N`, `M`, and `K`, each denoting the original price, the minimum price, and the
amount Jojo is going to buy.

Format Output

For each test case, print “Case #X: “ (X starts with 1), then followed by the price Jojo has to pay rounded to 3
decimal digits.

Constraints

1 <= `T` <= 10

1 <= `M` <= `N` <= 1,000,000,000

1 <= `K` <= 1,000,000,000

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        int T;
        scanf("%d", &T);

        for (int i = 1; i <= T; i++) {
            int M, K, N;
            scanf("%d %d %d", &N, &M, &K);

            float halfPrice = N;
            float sum = halfPrice;

            for (int j = 0; j < K-1; j++) {
                halfPrice /= 2;
                halfPrice = (halfPrice < M) ? M : halfPrice;
                sum += halfPrice;
            }
            printf("Case #%d: %.3f\n", i, sum);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Your approach is working too hard. The inner loop does `K` iterations (with could be as large as `1,000,000,000`), and most of them are redundant: as soon as `halfPrice` goes beyond `M` it will stay beyond `M` for the rest of the loop. Notice that in the worst case (`N = 1,000,000,000`, and `M = 1`) you'll need just 30 iteration to reach `M`. So, something along the lines of

  ```
      int halvings = 0;
      while ((halfPrice > M) && (halvings < K)) {
          sum += halfPrice;
          halfPrice /= 2;
          halvings++;
      }
      sum += (K - halvings) * M;
  ```

  will run up to 30,000,000 times faster.

  Now, the entire loop is in fact unnecessary. As Jojo applies the promotions (say, `P` times), the amounts he pays form a geometrical progression: \$N + \frac{N}{2} + \frac{N}{4} + ... + \frac{N}{2^P}\$.

  It is easy to sum. The accumulated price he pays here is \$(1 - \frac{1}{2^{P+1}})*N\$. The only thing left is to determine `P`. Recall that it is such that \$\dfrac{N}{2^P} \ge M\$ and \$\dfrac{N}{2^{P+1}} \lt M\$. An accurate application of `log` computes it immediately.
- Beware of the accuracy. During long summation the unavoidable floating point errors do accumulate. They accumulate even more when you add a very small number to a very large one. This phenomenon manifests quite surprisingly: floating point addition is not associative.

  This is why it is recommended to do summation other way around: start from small values and work towards the large ones. I don't know if this particular problem is subject to such kind of numerical instability or not. You may want to experiment. In any case, this is necessary to know when tackling floating point.

Comment: Good performance ideas.

Answer (score 3):

**Formatting**
This may be a copy and paste error, but generally `int main()` will start in the first column like the #include does. Other the rest of the indentation needs to be based on that. This was correctly done in your earlier question.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int T;
    scanf("%d", &T);

    ...

}
```

**Functions**
You may not have run into difficult problems yet, but as the programs get more complex the best way to solve them will be to break it up into smaller pieces where each particular task is easy to solve. In this case the outer for loop would make a good function. Perhaps the inner loop would make a second good function.

**Variable Names**
Variable names should be meaningful to make the code more readable, easier to understand and maintainable.

The problem statement gives you the variable names `T`, `N`, `M` and `K` which are currently being used in the code, however, it also gives you what the variables are used for. It might be better to use names such as `testCount` for `T`, `maxPrice` for `N`, `minPrice` for `M` and `itemCount` for `K`.

The variable name `halfPrice` could be misleading be it won't always be half of the maximum price.

**Mixing Types in Comparisons**
There is the possibility of [Floating Point Error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point_error_mitigation) in the code because of this comparison:

```
            halfPrice = (halfPrice < M) ? M : halfPrice;
```

While the minimum price is input as an `integer` it might be better to convert it to a `float` and use that in the comparison. This conversion should only be done once per test case.

In many cases banks work around this by keeping amounts in 2 integer values, one for dollars and one for cents (units are USA, units may differ based on location).

Comment: In the comparison, `M` is promoted to float automagically.

Answer (score 2):

**Precision**

`1 <= M <= N <= 1,000,000,000` implies a need for 30 bit of precision.  (log<sub>2</sub>1,000,000,000 --> 29.897...)

`float` [usually](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32) has 24 bits of precision (23 explicitly encoded, 1 implied).

Code as below can readily lose precision when converting from `int` to `float` for values of `N` > 2<sup>24</sup>.

```
float halfPrice = N;
float sum = halfPrice;
```

`double` [typically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) affords sufficient precision.

---

C [lacks a great type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32214586/2410359) to use for financial code.